# how to get claims of another user using ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I'm still learning identities with asp.net core. I'm doing a claims-based token authorization. 
Most examples are about "Current" logged in user. In my case my RPC service is receiving a username & password of some user in the identity DB. I need to

1. verify that a user with such credentials exist
2. get all the claims of that user

so to verify if the user exists, I'm using this:

```
ApplicationUser applicationUser = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(username);
bool exist = await _userManager.CheckPasswordAsync(applicationUser, password);
if (!exist)
{
    // log and return
}
```

I don't know how to do the 2nd step properly. I guess I could do a simple linq to collect all user's claims, but I'm sure there is a better way using the identity methods.

Comment: `_userManager.GetClaimsAsync(applicationUser)`?

Comment: that was it. I was complicating it with trying to get the principal user and the claimsIdentity of that user. Mark it as answer please.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to use the `GetClaimsAsync()` method. For example:

```
var claims = await _userManager.GetClaimsAsync(applicationUser);
```

See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn613142(v=vs.108).aspx)